# Option to take photo / select image from gallery in Expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am developing a mobile app using react native with Expo.
I need an option to take photo using Camera or select an image from the gallery.

Right now I have given 2 buttons one to take photo using camera and one to select image from the gallery uses `launchCameraAsync` and `launchImageLibraryAsync` respectively.
While bench marking other apps I have noticed that, most of the apps have single button which can access to camera from gallery, or access to galley from camera.
Is there a similar option available in Expo ?

Current implementation is as given below:

[image]

Thank you,
KK

Comment: You can easily let the user make a choice yourself.

Comment: Yea, currently I have kept 2 buttons. However, it would be cleaner if there is a single button, similar to apps like whatsapp and twitter.

Comment: You need only one button. On click let the user choose. That was what i suggested.

Comment: Oh ok, gotcha. But we still have to show 2 buttons isn't it ? one to choose camera, and one to choose the gallery. Is that right?

Comment: No. Only one button.

Comment: Sorry, I am bit confused. I have updated my question with the current implementation.

Comment: Your picture shows two choices. Not two buttons. Please show the code which produces this choice screen. To get such a screen the user has to click only one button.